# why does background-attachment works differently in body and div

Tags: html, css, background-attachment

I created a background and attached to body it is scrolling to the right fine. but when I attach to a div it doesn't seem to be attached. the scrolling happens in the body.

Here is the link when [attached to the body](https://codepen.io/skandasoft/pen/VwbRvEQ?editors=1100)

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

vs
when [attached to div](https://codepen.io/skandasoft/pen/poPYjxv?editors=1100)

Comment: inline-flex instead of flex (and min-width:100%)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The `.flex` div doesn't have a width set, so it only flexes to the viewport width.

Comment: Also read what background attachment is supposed to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: and width instead of flex-basis

Comment: @Quentin I think it is not a "my website doesn't work thing". It is a minimal reproduceable example...

Comment: @coool I think that comment was more about the fact your example was only available on an external site rather than in the question (Since any changes to the content at that link or if the site ever goes down, this question becomes meaningless)

Comment: @TemaniAfif  inline-flex and width does the trick.

Comment: @DBS yes absolutely agree